# Windows 7 Google Print Service

Tags: windows-7, printing, google-docs, google-cloud-print

I'm wondering if there's any way to use a custom Windows 7 print service to send documents directly to Google Docs.  My end goal is to use Google Cloud Print to be able to print any document from my computer to a remote printer, using Google Docs.  Might be a long shot, but thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

For Office Documents, try [OffiSync](http://www.offisync.com/download.html).  It allows you to save or open documents on your Google Docs directly from MS Office software.